# In iphone app, with 3 viewcontrollers with UInavigationcontroller, from 2nd to 3rd view, dealloc is not called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I am posting a question since there are similar problems to mine, but not exact.
I am new to iphone app development. 
I have 3 view controllers like below.

1 - Mapview controller is the 1st view controller and calls the 2nd table view controller by

```
[self.navigationContrller pushViewController:titlesViewController];

[titlesViewController release];
```

2 - titlesViewController is 2nd table view controller and in the DidSelectRowAtIndexPath method, it calls the 3rd view controller.

> ```
> @implementation TitlesViewController
> NSMutableArray *titleArray;
> NSMutableArray *bidArray;
> ...
> - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
> ...
>     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
>     [webView release];
>     [detailViewController release];
>     [titleArray release]; 
>     [bidArray release];
>     NSLog(@"****** titlesviewcontoller didSelectRowAtIndexPath");
> }
>
> - (void)dealloc
> {
>     [titleArray release];
>     [bidArray release];
>     [super dealloc];
>     NSLog(@"****** titlesviewcontoller dealloc");
> }
> @end
> ```

3 - detailViewController is the 3rd view controller to show detail info.
I did the Xcode profile->instruments->Memory leak, and there is a memory leak without

```
[titleArray release];
[bidArray release];
```

in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath in the 2nd table view controller.

I also noticed that with this app running in the IOS simulator, if I go to 3rd detail view from 2nd table view, the dealloc() method is not called, so there is memory leak without the 2 release codes for titleArray and bidArray. But if I go from the 2nd table view to the 1st view by pressing the Back button on the UINavitagation controller, the dealloc() is called. And so, no memory leak.

My question is do I really need the 2 release codes
**[titleArray release];
    [bidArray release];**
in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath in the 2nd table view controller. 
Is my observation correct?
I thought the dealloc() is invoked every time.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The memory is not necessarily leaked, since you might still have handler to it... I suspect there might be a cycle retain - cannot say for sure without seeing all the code. In case you have things like delegate, you need to use assign instead of retain.

Comment: You may be right, but When I did the memory leak test, the memory does not seem to be released but rather keeps increasing, indicated with yellow bar on the timeline.  When I use IOS simulator, the log message from the dealloc is not shown if I go to 3rd view controller from 2nd view controller, but the dealloc log message shows if I use back button to go to 1st mapview controller from the 2nd view controller. With this 2 release statements  in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath in the 2nd table view controller, there is no memory leaks detected in memory leak testing, and the app does not crash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to release ANYTHING you `alloc`. Nothing more. Nothing less. By explicit `release`, or by setting `autorelease` when allocating. If you don't alloc, you don't need to release : It's just a memory reference referencing nothing.

Why don't you put your global vars as member vars ? You should, that would be more clear. If it's not to make them available to other classes, well... Objective-C is not designed to do this. And anyway, using global vars is not recommended.

Comment: But it seems the dealloc is not called at all by the log message if I go from 2nd view controller to 3rd view controller.  Thus the memory does not seem to be released.  Originally, I put the global vars into the class member vars, but then this memory leaks occurs, so for a change, I put the vars out of the class into the global vars to see if this makes a difference.  I tried all kinds of stuff.Thank you.

Comment: @user1026669 : The place you put the vars does not affect memory leaks. Do keep in mind that Instruments can detect memory leaks, but is not perfect and can miss some others. Anyway, put the vars where they have to be, and check your alloc/retain/release calls to find where you have a retain that prevent deallocating. Also remember that if the memory occupation is a problem for you, you don't have to wait for the dealloc method being called to release yourself useless object (don't forget then to set them to nil after release).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I put the vars back in the class as member vars. Also, I put the 2 release codes in the ViewDidDisappear method, since it is called both backward and forward way, according to the log message that I put in. Do I have to set the 2 arrays to nil after the release statement?  Thank you.

Comment: @user1026669 : if they are property "retained", you just have to set self.array = nil. That will do a release. If you prefer call release for immediate release, setting them to nil after that is a good idea, but it's not a need. If the answer helped, could you please upvote / accept it ?